# LibGDX FreeTypeFontGenerator NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Have a method for generate BitmapFont

```
public BitmapFont GenerateFNTs(String pathToTTF, int fontSize) {
    fontHandle = Gdx.files.internal(pathToTTF);
    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(fontHandle);
    parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = fontSize;

    bitmapFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();
    return bitmapFont;
}
```

After run they throw me an exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/PixmapPacker$PackStrategy
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/PixmapPacker$PackStrategy
    at com.pol.helpers.GenerateFNT.GenerateFNTs(GenerateFNT.java:19)
```

What i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add all necessary dependencies like described here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#freetypefont-gradle ?